How to fix the " DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated." error with nestjs?
I am running a nestjs app and am getting the following error:
(node:28552) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

I have gone through all the answers and I have not found any solution for me. For instance I looked for require("punycode") to change it in node-modules folder files and this require is not written anywhere.
How is it possible to fix this please?
My start script is "start": "nest start".
For me, downgrading node version is not a solution.

This discussion describes how to find the package and what to do with it https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/66289

Does not work for me. I found the problem in the whatwg package. I modified the require. I installed patch-package and my app still shows the same error.

What is the whatwg package? Do you mean whatwg-url? The problem is discussed in https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url/issues/279 and https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url/issues/278. The solution seems to be an update of whatwg-url. The problem was fixed in v9.0.0 as you can read here: https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url/releases/tag/v9.0.0

whatwg-url package. Yes

If you still get the warning after the update, it's caused by another package.

running npm update -g whatwg-url shows version 5.0.0 in package.json

Ran npm install whatwg-url@latest and package.json shows version 14.0.0. Error still occurs. I need to find other packages.

Wow, whatwg-wg v5.0.0 was released 2017. You should upgrade your dependencies. "Error still occurs." That's not an error. It's only a warning. There is no problem. The package will be removed in the future. Until then, you can still use it.

I've created a new Nest project with Node v22.9.0 and npm v10.8.3 according to https://docs.nestjs.com/ and I don't get this warning. Maybe you're using an outdated package that wasn't fixed. In that case, you obviously can't solve this problem with an update. You can either fix that package yourself or find an alternative package.

AS of today, I updated all my packages to their last version using ncu and npm install.
The warning is still here.

This doesn't answer the question. Maybe, if you would provide a [mcve], someone could reproduce and solve your problem.

This answer the question from my point of view as the warning still remains after an update of all the packages. Following your recommandations, I will stay with the warning.

The question is "How to fix the " DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated." error with nestjs?" Your answer describes, how to not fix it. The correct answer is to find the package and either update or replace it. As I commented under the question, I can't reproduce the problem. I've created a new Nest project with Node v22.9.0 and npm v10.8.3 and I don't get this warning. Either your project is outdated or you use an outdated additional package. Both problems can be solved.
